# Applying a function to find high density area of a distribution (coding)

Tags: r, function, statistics, distribution, bayesian

**Background:**

Recently, I came across [**an R function called HDIofICDF**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42986446/determining-high-density-region-for-a-distribution-in-r/42987104#42987104) (**also see below**) that provides two limit-values for any distribution (a unimodal curve) such that from one limit-value to the other limit-value covers 95% highly dense area of that distribution.

The code requires that user put **Inverse cdf** of a distribution. For R-recognized distributions, this is achieved by "`qdistribution name`" e.g., `qf`, `qchisq` etc., and "`,`" and then the arguments needed for the "`qdistribution name`". For example for an F distribution finding the two limit values is possible via:

`HDIofICDF( qf , df1 = 10 , df2 = 90 )` OR for a Chi-Square Distribution, one can use: `HDIofICDF( qchisq, df = 10)`

**Coding Question:**

Suppose I have created my own distribution and have the **Inverse cdf** of this distribution. My **Inverse cdf** (similar to a "`qdistribution name`" in R) is given when I use (just as an example to show what arguments my **Inverse cdf** uses):

`invcdf.posterior(p = .025, t = 2.81, N1 = 10, N2 = 10, rscale = 1 )`

**Now:** given my `invcdf.posterior` and its arguments above, how can I use the **HDIofICDF** function to obtain the two limit-values for my distribution?

Here is **my R codes I have:**

```
HDIofICDF = function( ICDFname , credMass=0.95 , tol=1e-8 , ... ) {

 incredMass = 1.0 - credMass
 intervalWidth = function( lowTailPr , ICDFname , credMass , ... ) {
 ICDFname( credMass + lowTailPr , ... ) - ICDFname( lowTailPr , ... )
}
optInfo = optimize( intervalWidth , c( 0 , incredMass ) , ICDFname=ICDFname ,
                  credMass=credMass , tol=tol , ... )
 HDIlowTailPr = optInfo$minimum
 return( c( ICDFname( HDIlowTailPr , ... ) ,
         ICDFname( credMass + HDIlowTailPr , ... ) ) )
}
##########################################################################
## Example 1 of use: ##

HDIofICDF( qf , df1 = 10 , df2 = 90 ) ## This is a F distribution working OK
```

### THIS IS HOW I TRIED TO APPLY THE HDIofICDF function TO MY OWN DISTRIBUTION:

```
HDIofICDF( invcdf.posterior, t = 2.81, N1 = 10 , N2 = 10, rscale = 1 ) ## Not working
```

**The error I get is:**

`Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 
  argument "t" is missing, with no default
Called from: eval(expr, envir, enclos)`

Comment: You say "not working", but what do you mean with that? Do you get a wrong result, or an error message? And if so, what is the error message?

Comment: @JorisMeys, I just edited my post look at the very bottom please. My most important question is that: Am I correctly applying my  `invcdf.posterior` inverse dist. function to the HDIofICDF function or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that your `HDIofICDF` function has an argument `tol`.

Because of partial argument matching, when you call `HDIofICDF(invcdf.posterior, t = 2.81, N1 = 10 , N2 = 10, rscale = 1)`, the `t` that you specified is assumed to mean `tol`. (You can verify this by modifying your `HDIofICDF` function to print `tol`.)  Because of this, when your `invcdf.posterior` is subsequently called, R complains that the `t` argument is missing.

Here's a toy example illustrating what is going on:

```
fun1 <- function(a, b) a + b
fun2 <- function(aaa, ...) fun1(...)
fun2(a = 1, b = 2)
# Error in fun1(...) : argument "a" is missing, with no default
fun2(aaa = 99, a = 1, b = 2)
# [1] 3
```

As suggested by the example above, to get around your problem, explicitly specify `tol` in your call to `HDIofICDF`, e.g.

```
HDIofICDF( invcdf.posterior, t = 2.81, N1 = 10 , N2 = 10, rscale = 1, tol = 1e-8)
```